# Android Error "custom binary blocked by frp lock" When Debugging Over Wifi

Tags: android

I am developing a small Android app, and debugging using Samsung Galaxy phone (first with S6 and later S7).
After several times of debugging the application, the phone has suddenly entered a **"custom binary blocked by frp lock"** and stopped responding.

I haven't rooted the phone, so there is no custom binary I can think of.
I did use a 3rd party framework which uses JNI, but I don't know if it is related:
[Android USB Camera](https://github.com/jiangdongguo/AndroidUSBCamera)

Since I am writing an application which uses a USB camera, I I am debugging over Wifi. 
This situation happens after several time I debug, and after a few hours of work.

Any idea what causes this? Is it a malware in the 3rd party library?